# Use azure blob storage for git lfs

Tags: git, azure, git-lfs

I am using git-lfs to store certain large datasets in my work. However, the free tier of git-lfs has a bandwidth limit of 1GB/month, beyond which a user gets blocked for a month.
I happen to have some azure credits and want to use the blob storage as the storage for git-lfs while I version my project using git.

I ran into this repository using aws-s3 storage : [git-lfs-s3](https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3).

But it doesn't have enough instructions on how to set up the whole system and has also been archived by the user. Are there any other (well explained) solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [DVC](https://dvc.org/) for this. Although it is not EXACTLY the same as `git-lfs` since it requires the installation of DVC, it works very similar to  `git-lfs`. Over that, it works with cloud applications like google-drive, azure blob storage and more.

#### Setting up DVC

Post [installation](https://dvc.org/doc/install/linux#install-from-repository), inside the repository, **initialize dvc**:

```
dvc init 
dvc add path-to-large-file
```

DVC will ask you to run a git command to add the pointer file and ignore the large file from your commit. eg

```
git add path-to-large-file.dvc .gitignore
git commit -m "Add data file"
```

Post this you need to setup a remote where you want to save your large files. [Detailed Documentation](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/add#supported-storage-types) about using various remote sources (google drive, blob, aws s3, so on..)

```
dvc remote add -d myremote azure://mycontainer/path
```

Save your large files to the remote using:

```
dvc push
```

#### Using DVC

You have to only add the `.dvc` files for modified large files henceforth (assuming you had done a `dvc add` for the file at least once). Everything else will work like normal git.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLKBcPonMYw) is a well-explained tutorial on getting started with dvc for bypassing the limits of git-lfs.